# My functions will not interact. That or it wont return the value

Tags: c++

So I have been working at this awhile with no luck. The first function is working as I confirmed it by using cout for each variable and the equation is correct because i tried it without the function. The problem is that function1engineer does not assign distance a value and so it goes to its default double value. How do I make function1engineer accept the inputs from the first function?

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;
//angle*PI/180 to work in c++ for angles.
void function1customer(double& x1, double& x2, double& y1, double& y2);
double function1engineer(double distance, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2);

int main()
{
    int exitLoop;
    do
    {


        cout << "Choose an option.\n1: Given two points, compute the distance between them."
            << "\n2: Given two points, compute the horizontal angle from \nthe first point to the second."
            << "\n3: Given the elevation angle and velocity, compute the \n(horizontal) distance an object travels."
            << "\n4: Given a starting point, a distance, and a horizontal angle, \ncompute the destination point."
            <<endl;
        int opselect;
        cin >> opselect;
        switch(opselect)
            {
                //compute distance between 2 points
        case 1:
        double distance;
        double x1, x2, y1,y2;
        function1customer(x1,x2,y1,y2);
        cout << x1 << endl << x2 << endl << y1<< endl << y2 << endl;
        function1engineer;
        cout << setprecision(2)<< distance << endl;
        break;
            }
    cout << "Would you like to perform another calculation?\n0=No\n1=Yes" <<endl;
    cin >> exitLoop;
    }   
    while(exitLoop != 0);
}

void function1customer(double& x1, double& x2, double& y1, double& y2)
{
    cout << "Enter X1 cordinate in feet" <<endl;
    cin >> x1;

    cout << "Enter X2 cordinate in feet" <<endl;
    cin >> x2;

    cout << "Enter Y1 cordinate in feet" <<endl;
    cin >> y1;

    cout << "Enter Y2 cordinate in feet" <<endl;
    cin >> y2;
}

double function1engineer(double distance, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
    distance = 0;
    distance = pow(  ( pow((x2-x1),2.0) + pow((y2-y1),2.0)     ),(1.0/2));
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to them! The line `function1engineer;` does nothing!

Comment: Thank you the compiler warnings really made easing my way around this problem a breeze I didnt even know those existed!

Comment: Yes, it's really unfortunate that compiler warnings tend to be disabled by default and so need to be explicitly turned on. The warnings can be incredibly useful and save a lot of time - this applies equally to beginners and experts, but beginners are often unaware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `distance` by reference, and there is no need to return it explicitly. (Just as you have done for the parameters of `function1customer`. Use this:

```
void function1engineer(double& distance, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
```

The calling code would be:

```
function1engineer(distance,x1,x2,y1,y2);
```

Comment: That did not cause any change unfortunately. The program still returns the default value for doubles

Comment: Can you check that the return type for function1engineer() is void?

Answer (score 0):

You must always initialize variables before using them. Also you can add a cout statement to function1engineer to make sure that it is computing the correct value.

The modified value for distance can be collected either by using it as reference or by collecting its value in the main function. The modified program will be.

```
double function1engineer(double distance, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
    distance = 0;
    distance = pow(  ( pow((x2-x1),2.0) + pow((y2-y1),2.0)),(1.0/2));
    cout << "Distance" << distance << endl;
    return distance;
}
```

modify the call in main function to

```
distance = function1engineer;
```